# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (iTextSharp c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have a download PDF handler:

```
    // Build the PDF
    Manual.Functions.createEntireManual(ThisDownload.FileLocation);

    // Download file
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.Buffer = false;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Construct2-Manual-Full.pdf");        
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString());
    context.Response.TransmitFile(Settings.ManualBinLocation + ThisDownload.ID + ".pdf");
    context.Response.Close();
```

The create manual function looks like this:

```
public static void createEntireManual(string PDFPath)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Document d = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    d.Open();

    using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter p = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, new FileStream(PDFPath, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        d.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));
    }            
}
```

This throws the error:

```
Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\manuals\26.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
```

Fine, so I add `d.Close()` in my function:

```
        d.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world!"));            
    }    
    d.Close();        
}
```

But this throws:

```
Exception Details: System.Exception: The document is not open.
```

On the `d.Close()` line.  I've tried adding the new Document object as a using statement but it doesn't like this, throwing the nonsensical error:

```
Exception Details: System.Exception: The document is not open.
```

On the using close bracket.

Anyone more experienced with iTextSharp help me out here?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer, but you probably need to close that `FileStream` you created, not the `iTextSharp.text.Document`. I'm not in front of VS, so I'm not able to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you **need** to save the PDF to the file system? Otherwise, it's much easier to use the `HttpResponse` object's `OutputStream` directly. Here's a simple example:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="handlerExample" %>
using System;
using System.Web;
using iTextSharp.text;  
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public class handlerExample : IHttpHandler {
  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader(
      "Content-disposition", 
      "attachment; filename=Construct2-Manual-Full.pdf"
    );  
    using (Document document = new Document()) {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(
        document, Response.OutputStream
      );
      document.Open();
      document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
    }
  }
  public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

So saying you shouldn't use the `using` statement is incorrect. The example above is simplified, but can easily be extended; from the way you named your method above, maybe you're building a PDF manual from a number of different smaller PDF documents?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, you shouldn't use `using` at all for either the `Document` or `PDFWriter` object.  This code works:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the entire manual as PDF
    /// </summary>
    public static void createEntireManual(string PDFPath)
    {
        Document d = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, new FileStream(PDFPath, FileMode.Create));
        d.Open();
        d.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
        Image Cover = Image.GetInstance(Settings.ManualBinLocation + "cover.png");
        Cover.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        d.Add(Cover);
        d.Close();              

    }
```

Comment: static methods? no locks? asp.net? filesystem? recipe for concurrency disaster.

Comment: @z0n what's the best way to do it?  I need it to build the PDF, then serve it.

Comment: Think about what happens if two people request the same as-yet uncreated PDF at roughly the same time. Here's a great concurrency and threading tutorial I always recommend: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: @x0n by design two people won't download the same manual.  It's not reflected in the code same though.

Comment: It's not enough to say it - what happens if two people downloading different manuals at the same time hit your code?

Comment: @x0n what do you think will happen?  As far as I can tell in my code everything should work OK.